How to test if change-point in b-spline is statistically significant?
I'm interested in testing if the difference between 2 slopes one either side of a knot is statistically significant. Ignoring the model assumption violations with this example, how would one see if there was a significant change in the relationship/slope between x and y in the plot below? I've never used linear regression with the b-spline command before, do the p-values signify this difference between the two lines? I'm using the data "mtcars" as a stand-in for my own data.
Example:

library(ggplot2)
library(splines)

data(mtcars)

Is there a significant change point at wt=3?
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype="dashed", color = "red") + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm",
              formula=  y ~ splines::bs(x, knots = c(3), degree = 1), se=F)


# Build model:
mod <- lm(mpg ~ bs(wt, knots = c(3), degree = 1), data = mtcars)

summary(mod)

    

Call:
    lm(formula = mpg ~ bs(wt, knots = c(3), degree = 1), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2027 -1.9072 -0.7627  0.9611  6.1070 

Coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                         32.246      1.383  23.313  < 2e-16 ***
bs(wt, knots = c(3), degree = 1)1  -12.884      1.764  -7.306 4.78e-08 ***
bs(wt, knots = c(3), degree = 1)2  -21.133      1.932 -10.937 8.32e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.689 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8137,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8009 
F-statistic: 63.34 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.614e-11

Possible related question:
Separate B-spline between knots and compare goodness of fit on each piece

The standard way to test for significance is to compare your model to a restricted version of it.  In this instance, a natural restriction is the usual linear regression mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars).  Your software will automatically test this if you include wt as a variable, as in summary(lm(mpg ~ wt + bs(wt, knots = c(3), degree = 1), data = mtcars)) (although this is a little crude because it relies on how lm drops collinear variables).  Equivalently, and more elegantly, use anova, as in anova(mod1, mod).

What I wonder, though, is why you are willing to let bs select the knots for you.  How are you choosing your knots for your actual data?

@whuber - the knot is pre-specified as equal to 3.  This is a linear regression with two line segments connecting at 3.

@jbowman Thanks.  I had mistakenly thought knots specified how many knots (including endpoints) were to be used and that (therefore) bs would choose the median in this instance.

Thank you both! For context, the "3" here represents a point in time in my data. I wanted to compare data from before and after an event. @whuber, just to make sure I understand this correctly - one option would be to split the data (df1 = before wt=3, and df2 is after wt=3), do a separate model for each subset of the data, then compare both models with anova?

Not quite, because splitting the models allows for the error variance to differ, too.  I am saying precisely what I wrote: try the code I posted!

Got it, thanks again!
